# Fill a cell with VBA if contents get deleted by User

Tags: excel, vba

I am designing a time report for my colleagues. There are cells which contain a (hidden) formula but are unprotected because I need the user to still be able to manually override the formula.

Now, if a user enters his/her own content and then deletes it again, the cell is empty, which is what I don't want, as it will only lead to confusion.

I want to write a VBA macro which recognizes if the cell contents in a previously declared range are deleted / empty and if they are deleted / empty, then a formula from another (password-protected and hidden) cell should be copied to the empty cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Intersect(Range("F9:I108"), Target)    
If Not myRange Is Nothing Then

'I'm guessing something with WorksheetFunction and possibly CountA,
'but I don't know how to make it work

End If
End Sub
```

The formulas which should be entered if the content of a cell (or of multiple cells) is deleted is always in line 117 (same worksheet). For example, if the user deletes G50, then G117's formula should be copied into G50 in the same way you usually copy formulas in Excel (so if there's a non-$-reference in G117 that points to A117, it should then point to A50 after the formula is copied to G50).

If possible, I want to work without loops--they always take so long to execute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you just have a user over-ride column, and then default to using that value over your calculated, protected column? Something along the lines of: `=IF(Sheet!UserColumn1="",Sheet!CalculatedColumn1,Sheet!UserColumn1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a super simple example that involves only ***3*** cells, **A1**, **A2** and **A3**.  You must modify this to accommodate your formula-cells.

We first create a secret worksheet *(called `secret`)*.  We place the formulas from **A1** through **A3** from the main worksheet into the secret sheet, but we store them as *Strings* rather than *Formulas*:

[image]

Then we put the following worksheet event macro in the main sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Formula = Sheets("secret").Range(Target.Address).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The sub monitors changes to the three cells and if any of them are cleared, that formula will be restored from the secret worksheet.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you and @PeterT! I used a combination of both your ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible answer. In order to copy the formula and have it maintain the "relative addressing" of the formula, you need to copy using the R1C1 notation. So a quick sub for this could look like

```
Option Explicit

Sub RestoreFormula(ByRef emptyCell As Range)
    Dim formulaWS As Worksheet
    Dim formulaCell As Range
    Set formulaWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set formulaCell = formulaWS.Range("A17")
    emptyCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaCell.FormulaR1C1
End Sub
```

The important line here is the `emptyCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaCell.FormulaR1C1` part.

Then, over in the `Worksheet_Change` event it could look like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim checkRange As Range
    Set checkRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A9")
    If Not Intersect(checkRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim changedCell As Range
        For Each changedCell In Target
            If IsEmpty(changedCell) Then
                RestoreFormula changedCell
            End If
        Next changedCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you and @Gary's Student! I used a combination of both your ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else ever has the same problem and maybe wants to use my solution, which is a combination of PeterT's and Gary's Student's suggestions (thank you both so much):

First I created a new worksheet, in which I copied all of the formulas I wish to retain. I made sure to copy them to the exact same cell as in the original sheet.

Then I appended this code to the original worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Bereich1 As Range
Set Bereich1 = Range("F9:I108") 'Do NOT enter multiple, non-contiguous ranges here! It crashes Excel!
If Not Intersect(Bereich1, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim changedCell1 As Range
        For Each changedCell1 In Target
            If changedCell1 = "" Then
                changedCell1.Formula = Sheets("Tagebuch_secret").Range(changedCell1.Address).Formula
            End If
        Next changedCell1
End If

Dim Bereich2 As Range
Set Bereich2 = Range("E112") 'instead duplicate the code snippet
If Not Intersect(Bereich2, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim changedCell2 As Range
        For Each changedCell2 In Target
            If changedCell2 = "" Then
                changedCell2.Formula = Sheets("Tagebuch_secret").Range(changedCell2.Address).Formula
            End If
        Next changedCell2
End If

End Sub
```

This works fine for every scenario in which cell contents get deleted, both if the user deletes contents of a single or multiple cells!

My next step is to make the _secret sheet very hidden, password-protect the workbook structure and then password-protect my vba project. Then only people who know the password (me) can destroy my file :)